# Capybara :visit goes to a random string path with Javascript enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, capybara-webkit, poltergeist

In my Capybara test, when I `visit partners_path`, or any other path for that matter, with `js: true` Capybara attempts to visit `/{random string}` (which isn't an actual route). I'm generating random strings for some test fixtures, but none of them match the random string in the path.

This error doesn't happen when JavaScript is disabled, and I've tried capybara-webkit, selenium, and poltergeist, all with the same results.

I can post some code snippets if that would be helpful.

EDIT

spec.rb and spec_helper files are included below.

```
## partners_index_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "Show all partners" do
  context "when logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      login_with_oauth
      create_partner_data
    end

    context "when accessing the partners index view", js: true do
      before(:each) do
        visit partners_path
      end

      scenario "..." do
        ...some tests here...
      end
    end
  end
end

## spec_helper.rb

require 'factory_girl'
require 'simplecov'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/spec/'
  add_filter '/config/'
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  config.default_formatter = 'doc' if config.files_to_run.one?

  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed

  config.before(:each) do
    Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL
    $mongo ||= [ Mongo::Client.new([ "#{ENV['MONGO_HOST_1']}" ], { database: "account_services_development" }),
                 Mongo::Client.new([ "#{ENV['MONGO_HOST_1']}" ], { database: "partner_services_development" }) ]

    $mongo.each { |m| m.database.drop unless m.nil? }
  end
end

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

Comment: Yes, please post some code here

Comment: The feature code would be really helpful. Also your spec/rails helper.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error to be in mocking the oauth login. I was generating a random string for the image url provided during google oauth2, and the view displaying that image was trying to find the path to the random string. Replaced with `https://example.com` and everything is working fine.